# How to do error checking in php when the column value is empty in a table?

Tags: php

I have a `php code` as shown below in which I want to do error checking when the column value is empty in a table.

`PATH_FILE` and `FILE_NAME` are the name of the columns in a table.

```
$record['INFO']['PATH_FILE'] = A:\RW\YVR;

$record['INFO']['FILE_NAME'] =  ;
```

Let us suppose,
when there is nothing in the `FILE_NAME` column as shown above then `a tag` would like this `<a href="A:\RW\YVR\">` (its gonna like weird).

**php code:**

`echo '<td rowspan="'.$hello_world.'"><a href="'.$record['INFO']['PATH_FILE'].'\\'.$record['INFO']['FILE_NAME'].'">'."\n";`   // **Line A**

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make at `Line A` so that when the column value is empty `($record['INFO']['FILE_NAME'] =  )` **or**  `($record['INFO']['PATH_FILE'] = )` then it should not download any document or open a file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you want to check the file is exists or not, check it out.

```
<?php

$file = $record['INFO']['PATH_FILE'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $record['INFO']['FILE_NAME'];
if( !empty($record['INFO']['PATH_FILE']) && !empty($record['INFO']['FILE_NAME']) && file_exists($file) === TRUE ){
  echo '<td><a>link</a></td>'; // replace your a tag at this line
}else{
  echo '<td>file note exists</td>';
}

?>
```

remember replace the `<a>` tag if the file exist

Comment: Technically, you are doing three things `1. ` If `PATH_FILE` is empty then don't go inside the if block. `2. ` If `FILE_NAME` is empty then don't go inside the if block.  `3.` If file doesn't exist then don't go inside the if block.